Mean difference Confidence interval Repeated measures anova
I´m doing 4 repeated measures (T1, T2, T3 and T4) with each subject in the same conditions to calculate repeatability. I have 10 subjects.
Could be correct to report posthoc mean differences 95% confidence interval, of a repeated measures anova like a repeatability value?
T1-T2: CI95 MD = -1.1 | 2.3
T1-T3:...
T1-T4:...
T2-T3:...
T2-T4:...
T3-T4:...
For example in this data we will be sure that in 95% times, the differences will be between -1.1 and 2.3, and will be the same that we have a max uncertainty of 2.3.

If the result of your two-way repeated-measures ANOVA indicates a significant difference in times and treatments with no interaction, using pairwise t-test with a correction factor (eg., Bonferroni's correction) would be right.
Ref: https://labs.la.utexas.edu/gilden/files/2016/05/Statistics-Text.pdf

The results are not showing significant differences...

But I think that confidence intervals for mean differences are independent from significance, no?

But I think that confidence intervals for mean differences are independent from significance, no? Could you please elaborate?

Mean difference are independent of significance. You can reporte always mean difference only to show the differences between groups, due the significance maybe not reflect the practical differences in real use.

Yeah, I suppose that would be a good way to reveal results.
Curious to know- you're still using a two-way repeated-measures ANOVA to test your hypotheses, right?
